# Find the sum of neighbors given integer

Tags: c++

Given a sequence of five integers. Replace these numbers, except the first and last, with the sum of their neighbors. Print the resulting numbers.

ok so coded and tested the code it gives me 10% that it works.I wounder where I am making mistake?The code seems ok and works fine but i can not get 100%.this is the homework just to let you know guys))Can you guys help me out to find where i am making mistake...

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a,b,c,d,f;
  cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>f;
  int b_1=(b-1)+(b+1);
  int c_1=(c-1)+(c+1);
  int d_1=(d-1)+(d+1);
  cout<<a<<b_1<<c_1<<d_1<<f;
}

//input 1 2 3 4 5
//ouput 1 4 6 8 5
```

Comment: Your code will **only** work if the numbers are in natural sequence. Try giving `3 6 2 1 9` as input, for example!

Comment: Clue: Try using an array.

Comment: Let me ask you this: What are `b`'s neighbors?  Does `b-1` or `b+1` equal that?

Comment: "Neighbor" as in the "neighboring numbers in the input sequence".

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the problem. I read it to be: `int b_1 = a + c`;

Comment: well, apologies for snarky comment, after reading it twice I see how one can misread the task as "neighbors of the numbers", ie neighbors of `x` would be `x-1` and `x+1`, however I (and others) am sure that this is not what is asked for, but rather "neighbors of the numbers in the sequence"

Comment: NathanOliver lets say b=3; neihgbour of 3 os 3-1 and 3+1 so 2+4

Comment: @ElgunQuliyev That's if you enter `1 2 3 4 5`.  What if I enter `1 3 5 7 9`?  What would `b`'s neighbors be then?

Comment: @ElgunQuliyev The task appears to mean "neighbors" in the sense of "the numbers that _were input_ before and after this number", not "the integers that precede and follow the number (in the sequence of natural numbers)".

Comment: @ElgunQuliyev 1) As already was explained, `(x-1)+(x+1)` is equivalent to `2*x`. Why would the task wouldn't just say "replace the number with twice the number", if it was, the case? 2) Why do you think, that "_except the first and last_" clause is in the exercise?

Comment: now i understand let me try to fix it @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica

Comment: let say b is 2 .the neighbor of 2 is 1 and 3 right?so 1+3 is 4

Comment: @ElgunQuliyev "_let say b is 2 .the neighbor of 2 is 1 and 3 right?so 1+2 is 3_" Depends on the sequence. If sequence is `1 2 3 4 5` - yes; if `5 2 4 3 1` - no.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstood the problem. The sum of the neighbors is the sum of the numbers right before and after a given number in the sequence. This seems evident from the fact that you are not supposed to calculate for the first and last numbers - which only have 1 neighbor each.

```
int a, b, c, d, e;
if (cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e) {
  cout << a << (a + c) << (b + d) << (c + e) << e;
}
```

Comment: i am so dummy)))now i understand))i am very new in the coding)))thanks a lott

Comment: @ElgunQuliyev It's a perfectly understandable mistake. You just misunderstood the teachers instructions. (And I upvoted your comment for the "thanks" part, not the "dummy" part.)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 thanks a lot for motivation :))))

Answer (score 0):

At first pay attention to your own message

> Given a sequence of five integers. **Replace these numbers**, except
>   the first and last, with the sum of their neighbors. Print the
>   resulting numbers.

So you need not just to output new values. You need to replace values of the variables.

You can do the task simply of to use standard function `std::exchange` declared in the header `<utility>`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d, f;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> f;

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    int tmp = std::exchange( b, a + c );
    tmp = std::exchange( c, tmp + d );
    std::exchange( d, tmp + f );

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, f = 5
a = 1, b = 4, c = 6, d = 8, f = 5
```

Another approach is to use the standard function std::swap. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d, f;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> f;

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    int tmp = b;

    b = a + c;

    std::swap( tmp, c );

    c += d;

    std::swap( tmp, d );
    d += f;


    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Again the program output is

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, f = 5
a = 1, b = 4, c = 6, d = 8, f = 5
```

You can simulate the function std::swap yourself. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d, f;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> f;

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    int prev = a;

    int tmp = prev;
    prev = b;
    b = tmp;

    b += c;

    tmp = prev;
    prev = c;
    c = tmp;

    c += d;

    tmp = prev;
    prev = d;
    d = tmp;

    d += f;

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, f = 5
a = 1, b = 4, c = 6, d = 8, f = 5
```

And at last the most simplified approach.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a, b, c, d, f;

    std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> f;

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    int tmp = b;

    b = a + c;

    c = tmp + d;

    d = f + b - a;

    std::cout << "a = " << a
              << ", b = " << b
              << ", c = " << c
              << ", d = " << d
              << ", f = " << f
              << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, f = 5
a = 1, b = 4, c = 6, d = 8, f = 5
```

Use the last approach.:) It is simple for beginners.